# Why can't the jarfile be found while deploying on heroku?

Tags: java, maven, heroku, dependencies

I keep getting an error while trying to deploy my app on heroku.

This is my pom.xml (build part):

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.24.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And this is my Procfile:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/web-runner.jar --port $PORT target /*.war
```

I keep getting this error:

Error: Unable to access jarfile target/dependency/web-runner.jar
2020-04-27T22:38:02.611229+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=joke-generator76.herokuapp.com request_id=53d259d1-f2a7-469f-bc09-efb6019f42f1 fwd="89.76.117.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-27T22:38:02.731866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=joke-generator76.herokuapp.com request_id=9b168a99-3bd1-4d15-bcf7-da703b4cd070 fwd="89.76.117.177" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

So, I guess, it cannot acces jarfile for some reason I can't understand.

Does anyone see what the problem might be? I searched all over official heroku's documentation, various dev blogs, other forums etc. I tried multiple solutions, but nothing works.

The code I provided here is actually what for many people RESOLVED the issue it causes for me, if information I found is to be trusted.

Also, on localhost the application runs without any troubles.

Please, help.

Answer (score 2):

the Procfile jar file (`web-runner.jar`) and the POM file destFileName (`webapp-runner.jar`) do not match

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution did resolve my initial issue, but now heroku gives me Error 404, saying that "The requested resource is not available". The logs tell me: `INFO: No global web.xml found` and `INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time` Any idea why would it give me 404 if the app works locally just fine?
`

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. I changed my POM entirely and deleted Procfile altogether. Now it functions no problem. I guess I just delved into configuration taken care of by the server itself. Adding my new POM below:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

It now functions on Heroku just as well as on localhost.